# variables of Fourier analysis - how to prove their relations

Tags: fourier-analysis

Fourier transform: $\hat{f}(\xi) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)\ e^{- 2\pi i t \xi}\,dx$
where $t$ can be time and $\xi$ can be frequency.
So, the question is how do we prove that $t$ and $\xi$ can in fact be time-frequency combination?

Comment: What is your question? Can you describe a bit further, e.g. what is "time-frequency combination"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiply them and check that $t\xi\in \Bbb R$.